# Characterizing the invertibility of linear transformations with its kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $(W,\mathbf{F})$ be a finite-dimensional vector space. Let Prove that $T:W \rightarrow W$ linear is invertible if and only if $\text{ker}(T) = \{0\}$.

One direction is quite simple, suppose that $T$ is invertible, but that there exists $w \neq 0$ such that $Tw=0$. Then $T^{-1}(Tw) = T^{-1}(0) = 0 \neq w$ contradicting $T$ being invertible. For the other direction, we try to do this directly. Assume that $\ker(T) = \{0\}$, then automatically $T$ is injective. How do I prove surjectivity? I am thinking of maybe showing that if $W$ has a basis, then the image of the basis elements under $T$ also form a basis for $V$. Not sure if this is a long way to do this or even the standard way. Is there a more "linear algebra" approach?

Comment: Have you tried rank nullity theorem?

Comment: @ShreyaChauhan: I am trying to complete this without rank nullity theorem

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested way is pretty standard, I think:

Let $\ker(T)=\{0\}$. Consider a basis $w_1,\dots,w_n$ of $W$. Denote $u_1=T(w_1),\dots,u_n=T(u_n)$. Let $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\in K$, s.t.
$$ \sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_ju_j=0.$$
This implies $\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_jw_j \in \ker(T)$ and thus $\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jw_j=0$, since
$$ T\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jw_j\right)=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jT(w_j)= \sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j u_j=0.$$
By the properties of a basis, this implies $\lambda_j=0$ for $j=1,\dots,n$, hence $u_1,\dots,u_n$ are linearly independent. Since by assumption $\dim(W)=n$, they are a maximal linearly independent family in $W$, hence a basis of $W$ and one obtains
$$\mathrm{im}(T)=\langle T(w_1),\dots,T(w_n)\rangle=\langle u_1,\dots,u_n\rangle=W. $$